# Spring security support multiple authentication types

Tags: azure, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I need to support 3 way of authentication at the same time in the application: LDAP, Azure AD, Basic.

After few hours of googling i found that the best way to do it would be to implement 3 authentication providers and then register them with AuthenticationManagerBuilder. But the issue i stumbled into is, that i dont know how the make the Azure Ad provider. For LDAP i found an online example i can use, and based on the LDAP i could probably also make the Basic username and password provider, but havent found anything similar on Azure AD. All i have found is that, i need to add 2-3 dependencies to the project for the Azure AD and then it automagically works.

I dont understand spring security that much, so im stumped atm. Can i just trust the automagic to do everything correctly, or are there some resouces on how to create AzureADAuthenticationProvider i could use with AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

Comment: Active Directory is an LDAP under the hood.

Comment: @Toerktumlare But how do i support normal LDAP and AD at the same time. As far as i have seen, is that they need separate configurations to work.

Comment: yes, you just need to set up two LDAP connections, like you would connect to two different databases and you can use this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: @Toerktumlare do you have some code sample with that integrated with spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory / spring-cloud-azure-dependencies?

Comment: nope, dont have that

Answer (score 0):

An authentication provider is an abstraction for accessing user information from LDAP, custom third-party source, database etc. it validates the user credentials.

**Spring security with azure ad:**

- Firstly, azure ad is integrated with Spring security for secure your application.

1. User login through their credential and get validate by azure AD.
2. From azure graph API you have to access token and membership information.
3. Membership for role based authorization.

**LDAP Authentication:**

1. Unique LDAP or DN ,you can perform search in directory unless you know username to DNS is known in advance.
2. You can authenticate the user by binding that user.
3. Load the Number of authorities for the user.

**Custom Authentication Provider:**

- Create own authentication (custom) with the help of authentication provider interface in which you can use
- authenticate method and implementing it and make authentication object with username and password of user
- Then after you can configure these authentication in  spring security configuration.

Here is the Reference [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html) regarding Spring Security